# What is the best lens car photography on a nikon d5200?

Tags: nikon-d5200

I currently have the Nikkor AF-S 18-55mm, but I'm looking to upgrade. I know there isn't necessary a "car photography" lens, but I'm looking for more of a 'car advertisement' look. I've heard that wide angle lens would be the better choice. I'm not shooting moving cars or have a standard backdrop. This is just one car in several different locations. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a bit broad - do you have examples of what you mean? Note that most of the 'car advert look' is going to be in the lighting & car prep.

Comment: I apologize! I'm unsure exactly on how to explain it. I understand what you mean by prep, but I was looking for a crisp, clean shot that will show the curves and detail of the car. Per say, the depth which is why I assumed the wide angle lens. The lens I have now is a starter lens and it does a pretty good job capturing what I'm  looking for, but I want a cleaner look. I apologize for the rambling and unclearness of what I'm wanting. It may have more to do with the settings on camera than lens. I'm still a newbie lol

Comment: Actually, I'd be interested in making this a bit *more* broad in one way. Would you be open to editing this to be "What lens type is best to get a typical 'car advertisement' look?" rather than making it specifically about your particular camera?

Comment: @mattdm, just me, but opening it up so that it's not a shopping question, Nikon, model-, or even lens-specific seems ideal. I'd go for something more like "What do I need to make that car-ad look?" We all know a lens is probably the least of it, and that even just stopping down the kit might work with the right lighting.

Comment: Related: [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006) and [D5100 Car Photography Settings Recomendations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26087). Maybe also see: http://www.thedrive.com/opinion/21386/14-secret-tips-to-taking-great-car-photos-from-a-professional-automotive-photographer

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I think wide angles are not that great as they will distort the curves and lines of the car.  Sometimes you need to use a wide if you are stuck having to shoot close, but it doesn't really create the best car images.

Here is a shot with a 15mm, but as you can see, it is distorted and not really the best representation of the Corvette, but I was limited in the distance I was able to work, so it had to do.

[image]

When you have the flexibility of working distance, I definitely like the telephotos like 85mm or even 200mm.  Here is a classic Camaro I shot with at 200mm which I feel has better results.

[image]

Comment: Compulsory link to my own very rough attempt at a one-time opportunity - the cars were amazing... I wasn't ;-) https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93129/one-time-opportunity-visiting-a-museum-plan-of-action

Comment: Mansell's car unfortunately rather soft :\. The second car though is a bit better. Need more depth by either smaller apertures or shooting further away then cropping - since you were using a 50mm, changing apertures is not an option.  If you were limited in working distance, shooting with a wider lens would yield more depth of field for more sharpness of the cars.

Comment: I shot what I could :/ Couldn't get any further back, couldn't get any more light. I took my fastest lens as a 'just in case' & had to shoot wide open at 1.4. Had I not, I'd have had nothing but noise. It was *dark* in there & my fastest wide [a zoom] is only 3.5.

Comment: Sometimes we do what we must.  If I was in that situation, I would try to get different focal points and focus stack the image to give an artificial wider depth of field.

Comment: We also had a whole 20 mins before they wanted us out again, so it was flat panic time & 100 cars to see. It wasn't optimal by any stretch of the imagination - but how many times are you going to get to see the entirety of Frank Williams' collection in your lifetime?  ;)

Comment: Definitely. In that situation it would be shooting second on the list of priorities for sure. If it was work though, different priorities ;).

Comment: Not work, just an opportunity, as a fan, to go to the Williams factory [with 100 other people, all milling around & getting in the way] for a business meeting. More than half the challenge was getting a frame with no-one standing in the way.

Comment: I certainly know how that is.  The image of the Corvette was at the Orange County Auto Show.  Taken a lot of standing around waiting for the right moment.